# How to reformat a timestamp in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, text, methods

I have some text below that needs to handled. The timestamp is currently listed and then the value. The format for the timestamp is `yyyymmdd` and I want to be able to alter it to `yyyy-mm-dd` or some other variation: `yyyy/mm/dd`, etc. I can't seem to find a string method that inserts characters into strings so I'm unsure of the best way to do go about this. Looking for efficiency here and general advice on slicing and dicing text in python. Thanks in advance!

```
19800101,0.76
19800102,0.00
19800103,0.51
19800104,0.00
19800105,1.52
19800106,2.54
19800107,0.00
19800108,0.00
19800109,0.00
19800110,0.76
19800111,0.25
19800112,0.00
19800113,6.10
19800114,0.00
19800115,0.00
19800116,2.03
19800117,0.00
19800118,0.00
19800119,0.25
19800120,0.25
19800121,0.00
19800122,0.00
19800123,0.00
19800124,0.00
19800125,0.00
19800126,0.00
19800127,0.00
19800128,0.00
19800129,0.00
19800130,7.11
19800131,0.25
19800201,.510
19800202,0.00
19800203,0.00
19800204,0.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime

with open("stuff.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Remove initial or ending whitespace (like line endings)
        line = line.strip()

        # Split the timestamp and value
        raw_timestamp, value = line.split(",")

        # Make the timestamp an actual datetime object
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(raw_timestamp, "%Y%m%d")

        # Print the timestamp separated by -'s. Replace - with / or whatever.
        print("%s,%s" % (timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), value))
```

This lets you import or print the timestamp using any format allowed by [strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

> general advice on slicing and dicing text in python

The slice operator:

```
str = '19800101,0.76'
print('{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(str[:4], str[4:6], str[6:]))
```

Read: [strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) (look for the part on slices), and [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting).

Comment: Thanks! How would I use this efficiently and read the file (there are many entries) and loop through only changing the timestamp while leaving the value (after comma) alone?

Comment: @Yuri Read the whole file and go through each line (eg with [`readline()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline)), applying the format function on it.

Comment: Sorry it's still not clear to me. readlines() seems to put it all in a list which then can't be manipulated by the string formatting. Sorry to be a pest, but could you provide an example? I've tried a few things and haven't been able to get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Strings are not mutable so inserting characters into strings won't work. Try this:

```
date = '19800131'
print '-'.join([date[:4],date[4:6],date[6:]])
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I use this efficiently and read the file (there are many entries) and loop through only changing the timestamp while leaving the value (after comma) alone?